# Search inside array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an array, which is formatted as such:

```
var clients = [{
    "id": 1, 
    "hash": 5c5fbbb047984ca8eec6dc7a3d994c09, 
    "more": {...}
  }, 
  {
    "id": 2,
    "hash": 620628ce37817a94476d55e55a543bee,
    "more": {...}
  }, 
  {...}, 
  {...}];
```

It contains around 25 objects, but this can change. My program gets an ID, which is an integer, and what it has to do it look in the clients array, and find the object with the specified ID, and then remove that object from the array.

What is the best, most efficient way to do this, given that there could be a relativly large number of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function, like this

```
var clients = [{"id": 1, "hash": "5c5fbbb047984ca8eec6dc7a3d994c09"},
               {"id": 2, "hash": "620628ce37817a94476d55e55a543bee"}];
var idToRemove = 1;

clients = clients.filter(function(currentObject) {
    return currentObject.id !== idToRemove;
});

console.log(clients);
```

**Output**

```
[ { id: 2, hash: '620628ce37817a94476d55e55a543bee' } ]
```

Comment: Any reason for using bracket notation over dot notation?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array and delete the entry with a given `id`.

```
function removeClient(clients, id) {
  for(var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
    if(clients[i].id === id) {
      clients.splice(i, 1);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

You can also use the [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function for this, but I like this iterative solution better for two reasons:

- It exits once the client is found and removed, instead of always going through the entire array.
- It works on IE8 and lower, whereas `Array.prototype.filter` is an ECMAScript 5 feature that was not supported by IE until IE9.

Comment: ES5 methods didn't hit IE until 9. ;-)

Comment: @cookiemonster Thanks for pointing that out, I've corrected the post.

Comment: +1 since you're actually removing the item from the array instead of overwriting with a new array. This could make a difference.

Comment: There is `node.js` tag. I believe almost all of the latest versions support `filter` :)

Comment: @thefourtheye Good point. I like developing for node.js so much more than for browsers for that very reason.

Comment: @PeterOlson Same here bro :)